# Correct way to shorten code with many casts and obvious patterns in C#

Tags: c#, .net

So, I have an app that is doing some painting on screen. I'm operating with doubles, but to paint, I have to use floats or ints. So, stuff like this happens frequently:

```
g.DrawEllipse(monsterPen, new Rectangle(
  (int)Math.Round(x - (double)sizeVessel * 9.0 / 20.0), 
  (int)Math.Round(y - (double)sizeVessel * 9.0 / 20.0), 
  (int)Math.Round(sizeVessel * 18.0 / 20.0),
  (int)Math.Round(sizeVessel * 18.0 / 20.0)));
```

While it could look like this

```
g.DrawEllipse(monsterPen, NewRectangleFromD(
  x - (double)sizeVessel * 9.0 / 20.0),
  y - (double)sizeVessel * 9.0 / 20.0),
  sizeVessel * 18.0 / 20.0,
  sizeVessel * 18.0 / 20.0)));
```

Or even like this

```
DrawCircle(g, monsterPen, x, y, sizeVessel * 9.0 / 20.0)
```

However, I'm not sure how to better do it.

In C/C++, if my memory serves me well, you could make an alias, saying that, for example this code:

```
DrawCircle(g, p, x, y, r)
```

should be for all purposes treated as:

```
g.DrawEllipse(p, new Rectangle(
  (int)Math.Round(x - r / 2.0), 
  (int)Math.Round(y - r / 2.0), 
  (int)Math.Round(r), 
  (int)Math.Round(r))
```

But I can't find such option in C#. With no ability to force inline (I'm working in .Net 4.0) I am affraid that If I just declare a DrawCircle method that does that, I'll slow down my application (those draw calls are done quite often).

So, what is the correctt approach to take here?

Comment: Make an extention method?

Comment: @DavidG but does it have no extra cost? If I use an extension method, will the call stack look like this: (main -> call DrawCircle -> call DrawEllipse) or like this (main -> call DrawEllipse)?

Comment: There's a cost to everything, but I doubt this will cause anything noticeable.

Comment: Well, in case of alias, or inline, there is no cost - the short notation is equivalent to the long notation (only cost is in time it take to compile your code). Therefore I need a no-cost (at runtime) solution since it's obviously possible to achieve

Comment: @Istrebitel If you can use .NET 4.5, add `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` to your extension method. But in your case, the cost of calling one more function will most probably be negligible compared to the cost of drawing an ellipse and doing rounding.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski not available in 4.0 :(

Comment: If you're worried about a few more bytes on the stack, I have to remind you that c# is an interpreted language with a garbage collector that could pre-emptively suspend your application for tenths of a second. Perhaps c++ is where you really need to be with this project?

Comment: @KeithPayne Not true. C# is a JITted language, but the GC may be a concern indeed.

Comment: I seriously doubt the overhead of an exention method would have any impact. As @KeithPayne suggests, perhaps you need another language more suited?

Comment: I understand C# has it's performance or other negative issues that come with the benefits. This is a hobby project and C# / .Net was chosen just because it was most easy-to-use at that time for me. Here I'm just asking if I'm missing something... because I mean, aliases are so simple and useful, I thought there must be something akin to them in .Net, and I didn't want to go the wrong way (that is, write wrapper functions that introduce overhead cost)

Comment: @Istrebitel With a release build, you can reasonably rely on the JIT to inline your function anyway.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I consdered this... but found not enough concrete documentation on that. For example, what is meant by the "32 byte" limit? Should my whole function body, including spaces and linebreaks, be less than 32 letters?

Comment: Why do you need a zero impact solution? What makes you think any solution is not going to work?

Comment: @Istrebitel No. It's the size of the MSIL body of the function. But look... You're using GDI, which is about the slowest possible way of displaying graphics in .NET anyway. Just don't bother... you're doing premature optimization in the wrong place.

Comment: I understand I'm using slow method, when the solution in question was started I didn't knew how to use OpenGl or SDL for outputting primitives and now it will take a huge effort to port everything over. I guess you are correct that the relative impact will be miniscule, I just still don't want to add extra overhead if I can help it.

Comment: Anyway, thanks everybody, I think it's safe to conclude there is no "alias" or similar solution in C#. Meanwhile I'll use extension methods and hope they get inlined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use [extention methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class GraphicsExtentions
{
    public static void DrawEllipse(this Graphics g, Pen pen, double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(pen, (int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);
    }
}
```

Which you call like this:

```
double x, y, w, h;
...
g.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, w, h);
```

And if you want it to be super fast, you could look at the aggressive [inlining attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static void DrawEllipse(this Graphics g, Pen pen, double x, double y, double width, double height)
{
    g.DrawEllipse(pen, (int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. As I replied above, I'm looking for a no-cost solution because in this case it is obviously achieveable...

Comment: Why do you think it is "obviously achieveable"?

Comment: Consider this: I make a custom text editor, which edits .cs++ files. This editor introduces new syntax into C# akin to aliases in C++. It has an option to "export" cs++ file to cs file, in process of which aliases are replaced with whatever they alias. There, no-cost solution achieved. It would be clunky of course, as I'd have to edit my cs files outsdie of Visual Studio, and obviously I'd not be going with it, but it proves that this is possible. Now the question is wether this is implemented already in C# or not...

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Maybe I explained it in a bad way. What I tried to say is that you can create a script (algorithm? program?) that would introduce a way to do what I want by just replacing patterns in the file with C# code (like, changing all "DrawCircle" into "DrawEllipse" as mentioned above). It would mean you have to edit your code in another application, and then apply the script to produce a c# code file before you compile. So when I edit the code, I see "DrawCircle" and compact code, but in c# file, "DrawEllipse" and the expanded code is present (and sent to the compiler).

Comment: Obviously since Intellisense and other Visual Studio functionality is important for productivity, this would not be a feasible solution (I'd gain an ability to make my code look better, but I'd lose much more), but it's a proof-of-concept you can have a zero-cost solution for the problem of this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer here to point out why you shouldn't bother about that.

You're using GDI+, which is a software renderer. Doing intensive graphics with this library will be *painfully slow* anyway.

How many CPU cycles are needed to call a function? And how many are needed to actually draw an ellpise in software? I don't have the figures, but I'm sure of one thing: they'll be several orders of magnitude apart.

Conclusion: You're trying to optimize the wrong thing here. If you want to display graphics *fast*, use a hardware accelerated solution.

Comment: I understand I'm using a slow method, when the solution in question was started I didn't knew how to use OpenGl or SDL for outputting primitives and now it will take a huge effort to port everything over. I guess you are correct that the relative impact will be miniscule, I just still don't want to add extra overhead if I can help it

Comment: @Istrebitel My point is, you seem to underestimate how *negligible* is the impact. Even `Math.Round`, which you call 4 times, will have *much* more overhead than one more stack frame.

Comment: I got it. I do not want to argue wether or not something has significant impact, all I wanted was to not introduce extra overhead because I do not know a better solution, that's why I asked.